# É possível utilizar o Node.js como servidor para o PHP?

Tags: php, node.js

Estou interessado em saber se poderia utilizar o Node.js como servidor para o PHP. Se sim, como poderia fazer isso? Haveria algum problema em utilizá-lo?

Comment: Em princípio bastaria usar o `exec()` chamando o PHP, a pergunta maior seria "se você precisa do PHP, por que usar node?" e vice-versa. Dependendo da resposta, as formas de se resolver podem variar. https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Comment: no google, “nodejs as php server”

Comment: O comentário/pergunta do @Bacco faz muito sentido. Podes também correr PHP e Node no mesmo servidor sem que um esteja dependente do outro. Mas como referido, não é costume serem precisos os dois.